# Reindex field text into date leads error 'Rejecting mapping update to ...'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am totally new to elastic search and stack-overflow, So please forgive me if this is a stupid question and my questions might have been answered somewhere else already but I couldn't find it.

The elastic search version is 6.8.3.
There is an index names 'news' uses a text-based field names 'publishDate'.

```
GET news

{
  "news" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "news" : {
        "properties" : {
          "hId" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "mediaMc" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "mediaType" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "publishDate" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "ik_smart"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1621927068883",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "PkR2aJRDTxef5jsyjEW6Cg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6080399"
        },
        "provided_name" : "news"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the data looks like:

```
GET news/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}

{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 66995,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "news",
        "_type" : "news",
        "_id" : "s59tonkB6cOG1bTAOGy5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "hId" : "20210525c315b872c5a24fc6af7a208e5b8d7dfa",
          "title" : "《能源资本论》连载....",
          "publishDate" : "2021-05-24 14:33:23",
          "mediaType" : "01",
          "mediaMc" : "腾讯新闻"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "news",
        "_type" : "news",
        "_id" : "uZ9tonkB6cOG1bTAO2wU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "hId" : "202105258255e7ccc4834966b803a92efb39aac3",
          "title" : "西安租房新规！....",
          "publishDate" : "2021-05-24 15:30:18",
          "mediaType" : "01",
          "mediaMc" : "腾讯新闻"
        }
      },
    ....
```

Now I am going to sort hits by 'publishDate desc', and I do not think saving date as text is a good idea, so I am trying to create a new index names 'news_2', while 'publishDate' is defined as date.

```
PUT news_2

POST news_2/type/_mapping
{  
    "type": {
        "properties" : {
          "hId" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "mediaMc" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "mediaType" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "publishDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "ik_smart"
          }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then, I am trying to transport data.

```
POST _reindex
{
"source": {
    "index": "news"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "news_2"
  }
}
```

However, the operation does not works, it returns a list fulls with same error instead, one element is:

```
{
  "index": "news_2",
  "type": "news",
  "id": "s59tonkB6cOG1bTAOGy5",
  "cause": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [news_2] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [news, type]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So what mistake I made, and how can I do to make it works? I have searched Baidu but I did not found useful advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Since) Elasticsearch 6.0 has ***deprecated support for multiple types in a***
> ***single index***. Please see the notes here for the schedule of the
> removal of mapping types. I would suggest looking at your mapping and
> ***adjusting so there is only one type in a single index***.

Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/779#issuecomment-403077764

```
index `news`
properties - text
mediaMc - kewword
mediaType - keyword
publishDate - text
title - text
-----------------
index `news_2`
properties - text
mediaMc - kewword
mediaType - keyword
publishDate - date
title - text
-----------------
```

Let's focus at `publishDate`: it is `text` in `news`, and is `date` in `news_2` .

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it able to transfer publishDate from text to date by using script? Or I have to use an external tool to do that?

Comment: Change mapping type of target to the same with mapping type of source index, then the above error will not happen.